# Returning variables from public class C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following code

```
public class IDFMeasure 
{ 
    ,,,,,,,,,,
    ........


    public float [][] GetIDFMeasure(string[] documents)
    {
        _docs = documents;
        _numDocs = documents.Length;
        MyInit();
        return _termWeight;
    }
}
```

I want to call this class in the main program. How I do it ? I'm getting confused with class types.. Can any help please? Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call a class. You instantiate a class and call its methods. You can do so like this:

```
public void main() {
   IDFMeasure measure = new IDFMeasure();  // instantiate class
   float[][] vals = measure.GetIDFMeasure(documents); // now call method on that class
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create object of class and then call the method.

```
IDFMeasure obj = new IDFMeasure ();
float [][] arr = obj.GetIDFMeasure(new string[]{"1"});
```

If you only need to call the method and do not need object any more then you can create anonymous object and call method on it.

```
float [][] arr = new IDFMeasure().GetIDFMeasure(new string[]{"1"});
```